# Calling table with two AS variable and comparing them when table has only one row of data

Tags: sql, database

I'm trying to understand the AS function in SQL.

Let's say I have a table called `disaster` and I'm using this `from` clause in my query

```
from disaster as D, disaster as D2
```

My table disaster has only one row of data and for example one of the columns in the table is `dyear`.

If I try to check for equality between D1, D2 like this

```
D2.dyear = D1.dyear
```

will they be equal?

If I had one more row of data, they won't be equal right?

Thanks for helping me out!

The full code:

```
select distinct 
    D.cname, D.etype, D.dyear
from 
    disaster as D, disaster as D2
where 
    D.cname = D2.cname 
    and D.dyear < (date_part('year', current_date) - 100)
    and ((D2.dyear not between D.dyear and D.dyear + 100) or (D2.dyear = D.dyear))
```

I'm trying to make a table of all the cities that had a disaster at least 100 years less than this year, and that since that disaster there weren't any more disasters at least 100 years in this city

And I thought about trying to compare `D2.dyear` and `D.dyear` to see if there was only one disaster in the city

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I can't figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: Doing a self join with a one row table - what's the point?

Comment: Edited the post i hope i made it more clear for you friends

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

In your example `AS` is just a reserved word of a server that says that the following word is an [alias](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) for a table. Actually you may omit it and nothing gonna be changed.

**UPD** The next section is true only in case of `where` clause absence.

Writing two tables over a comma will produce the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) and the result will be corresponding. It's not a lever to compare data but a way of joining of tables.

Here is a sample code in SQL Server that does such a selection. It returns only a last disaster that was less 100 years. But you have a third column `etype` and it takes some extra code - add it into a `select` and `group by` and then filter a required value or something

```
with t as 
(
    select cname, datepart(year, dyear) disaster_date
    from disaster t
    where datepart(year, getdate()) - datepart(year, dyear) >= 100
      and not exists (select 1 
                      from disaster 
                      where cname = t.cname 
                        and datepart(year, getdate()) - datepart(year, dyear) < 100)
)
select distinct cname, min(disaster_date) disaster_date  
from t 
group by cname
```

Comment: OP actually is not running the cartesian product due to the `WHERE` clause expression: `D.cname=D2.cname`. This is actually the pre ANSI-1992 form of join (i.e., the implicit join) and not the current practice of using the explicit `JOIN`.

Comment: @Parfait it's true and I know about an implicit join, but the first revision of the question havn't had `where` clause)

Comment: OP edited 3 minutes before you answered so the full SQL code blook was available.